# get file list in android raw resource directory from code

Tags: android

I want to get a file list in raw resource directory. just as open a file directory and get all files in that directory.

Maybe we can just call system command to do it. but I am not sure how to find the correct file path of the raw directory.

Comment: Raw resources are files only on your development machine. They are not files on the device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need this:

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
    String name = fields[i].getName();
    @RawRes int rawId = (Integer)fields[i].get(null);
    // Do your thing here.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below string to access files in that directory.
e.g. if file test.mp4 is located at raw directory, you can access it with below string:

```
android.resource://com.example.package/raw/test
```

I am not sure if you can query all files in that directory!